# Pass an array in sd_setImage

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uicollectionviewcell

How can I pass an image array from the first controller **(collectionCell)** to the second controller **(collectionCell)** using **sg_setImage** and **class** (swift file) using **segue**?
To load an array of images onto the first controller, I use **collectionCell** inside **tableCell**.

**ViewController** (firstVC):

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var image: [Model] = []
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Студии2")

        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var newImages: [Model] = []

            for item in snapshot.children {
                let object = Model(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newImages.append(object)
            }
            self.image = newImages
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue1" {
            if let indexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let indexPath = indexPaths as NSIndexPath
                let dvc = segue.destination as! ViewController2
                dvc.photo = [image[indexPath.row]]
            }
        }
    }
}
extension ViewController1: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return image.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1
        cell.images = [image[indexPath.row].image,
                       image[indexPath.row].image2]
        return cell
    }
}
```

**tableViewCell** (firstVC):

```
class TableViewCell1: UITableViewCell {

    var images = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}
extension TableViewCell1: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return images.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell1

        cell.imagesView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: images[indexPath.item]))

        return cell
    }
}
```

**collectionViewCell** (secondVC):

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var photo: [Model] = []

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
extension ViewController2: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return photo.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell2
        let array = [photo[indexPath.item].image,
                     photo[indexPath.item].image2]
        cell.imagesView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: array[indexPath.item]!))
//        cell.imagesView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:            photo[indexPath.item].image2))
        return cell
    }
}
```

**class Model** (swift file):

```
class Model {
    var image: String!
    var image2: String!
    var images: [String] = []
    var images2: [String] = []
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        ref = snapshot.ref
        let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        let snap1 = value["hall1"] as? NSDictionary
        let snap2 = value["hall2"] as? NSDictionary
        image = snap1?["qwerty"] as? String ?? ""
        image2 = snap2?["qwerty"] as? String ?? ""
        if let post1 = snap1 as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for (_, value) in post1["images"] as! [String: AnyObject] {
                self.images.append(value as! String)
            }
        }
        if let post1 = snap1 as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for (_, value) in post1["images"] as! [String: AnyObject] {
                self.images2.append(value as! String)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I speak Russian, but it doesn't help much in understanding your question. can you please show more code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must be in English

Comment: Also, if you cannot ask it in english, there is a russian version of SO : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: thanks for changing the question to English, but you need to also update the title too!

Comment: replaced title too

Comment: Now, let's improve your question to make it more focused.  :-)  I have no idea what your `Model` object looks like.  Would you edit your question to show what kind of properties `Model` has?  You also say you use a collectionViewCell inside a tableViewCell.  That sounds confusing.  Maybe if you could explain this a little more.

Comment: i'm sorry, i added code :)

Comment: i can pass on String (not Model), but this String i can't pass to **thirdVC**, because in Model i have the array in which is included image and i would to see this array in **thirdVC**

Comment: there are no knowledgeable person :(